# Ghostscript PDF -> TIFF throws an untrappable exception, when consuming files with asian fonts

Tags: python, jython, tiff, ghostscript

Ghostscript curls up and dies, throwing an exception to stdout which I cannot catch and log. I am pretty sure it gets sick when I give it asian fonts. Has anybody backed into this problem and solved it?

Comment: How about some context on this Q? How are you executing the conversion? What platform?

Comment: @reedstrm: Looks like Setori is no longer interested in solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you need to read stderr from the child process.